# Flutter AnimationController with dynamic duration - error: Const variables must be initialized with a constant value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I want to set the animation duration from my widget parameter but it doesn't work because duration wants to be initialized with a constant

```
class CircularTimer extends StatefulWidget {
  CircularTimer({@required this.seconds});
  _CircularTimer createState() => _CircularTimer();
  final seconds;
}

class _CircularTimer extends State<CircularTimer>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<double> animation;
  AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(/*not working*/seconds: widget.seconds), vsync: this);
    animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 300).animate(controller);
    controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      CircularTimerWidget(animation: animation);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass data like this to `const`, so the solution would be either to remove `const` from `Duration` or simply use some `const` value.

Solution:1

```
controller = AnimationController(
  duration: Duration(seconds: widget.seconds), // remove const
  vsync: this,
);
```

Solution:2

```
controller = AnimationController(
  duration: const Duration(seconds: 1), // some const value
  vsync: this,
);
```